# Remove only the part after url and before #

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing

In address bar: `http://xxx/view/9204?category=bed#details`

Javascript:

```
var uri = window.location.toString();
if (uri.indexOf("?") > 0) {
    var clean_uri = uri.substring(0, uri.indexOf("?"));
    window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, clean_uri);
}
```

Found the snippet online, but it cut off the stuff after url. Wanted to take out only `?category=bed` part. Is there any way to take that part? 
Want the string: `http://xxx/view/9204#details`

Comment: so you need to get `http://xxx/view/9204#details`?

Comment: @cr0ss - yes need to get xxx/view/9204#details

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/u5K8p/

Comment: did you know that the whole `http://xxx/view/9204?category=bed#details` is the url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could replace the `search` part of the url with nothing, like this:

```
var yourURL = window.location.href.replace(window.location.search,'');
```

According to [this site](http://techtalk.virendrachandak.com/get-various-parts-url-using-javascript/):

> **window.location.search** - Returns the query portion of the URL, including the question mark
>
> **window.location.href** - Returns the entire URL.

Comment: There is also **window.location.hash** to round things out.

Comment: @Niklas - ah window.location.search works but how to return url. hmm

Comment: @kittymeows - I'm not sure what you mean? Return to where?

Comment: @Nikas - wanted to edit my comment but i wasnt able to edit. var uri = window.location.href; window.location = uri.replace(window.location.search,''); That's working.

Answer (score 0):

How about this, add the two substring fragments together:

```
var clean_uri = uri.substring(0 , uri.indexOf("?")) + uri.substring(uri.indexOf("#"));
```